# Ionic 3 nav controller back button not showing

Tags: javascript, ionic3

When opening a closed app from a push notification, the back button does not appear in the nav bar. If is the app is open the button appears.

I tried checking navController length and do insert a page if length is 0. But the back button still doesn't show up.

Any tips on how to get it working?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Title
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

constructor(navCtrl: NavController) {

  let lastNavLength = navCtrl.length();

  if (lastNavLength == 0) {
    console.log('empty');
    navCtrl.insert(0, TabsPage);
  }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
  private onPushOpened(payload: OSNotificationPayload) {
    if (payload.additionalData.eventKey) {
      this.notificationOpen = true;
      this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push('EventPage', {
        id: payload.additionalData.eventKey,
        event: payload.additionalData.event,
        action: 'tapped'
      });
    }
  }
```

-------------- Edit --------------------

app.component.ts

```
  private onPushOpened(payload: OSNotificationPayload) {
    if (payload.additionalData.eventKey && payload.additionalData.event) {

      this.notificationOpen = true;
      this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push('event', {
        id: payload.additionalData.eventKey,
        event: payload.additionalData.event,
      });
    }
  }
```

tabs.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TabsPage,
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(TabsPage),
    ],
})
export class TabsPageModule { }
```

tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage({
  name: "TabsPage",
  segment: "tabs",
})
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})

export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = 'HomePage';
  tab2Root = 'AboutPage';
  tab4Root = 'SettingsPage'

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

home.ts

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'HomePage',
  segment: 'home'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

event.ts

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'EventPage',
  defaultHistory: ['HomePage'] .. tried with TabsPage also.
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-event',
  templateUrl: 'event.html',
})
```

Comment: According to their docs *"Returns: The number of views in this stack, including the current view."* So wouldn't your `navCtrl.length()` be `1` if you're on the rootview?

Comment: It's not in rootview. It opens another page. Length is 0 when app is closed and 1 when open.

Comment: @Ivaro18 Yes. Your're right. It was showing 0 because I wasn't calling the code in the `OnInit` method. But even after moving it, the button still doesn't appear.

Comment: navCtrl.insert(0, 'TabsPage'); if lazy loading

Comment: So if your use case is to show back button (and there should be then a destination page where users can "go back" to) once a user gets into your app through notification you should leverage "default history" param of IonicPage component: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/. See section with "default history". Let me know if you struggle to implement it. This approach requires you to have deep linking. But I think it is a better approach for the use case as the other way around is more of a hack.

Comment: So just by adding the defaulHistory will make the button appear? I'll try it later and let you know how it works.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Please see my edit. It's still not working. Is there anything else needed? Do I need to define names? Like `@IonicPage({
  name: 'tabs',`

Comment: You need to implement deep linking and then leverage this param. Did you do it? Just adding param wont work

Comment: Isn't that done with IonicPageModule.forChild() ?